# Using Generator function to generate date

Tags: sql, select, subquery, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is the query I am using to generate last date of each week. However the filter does not seem to take affect. and the starting date I get is "2016-01-03".

```
SELECT TO_DATE(last_day(DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4()*7, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'), 'week')) AS WEEK_LAST_DATE
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>1000)) 
WHERE WEEK_LAST_DATE > '2016-09-07';
```

The following works though:

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT TO_DATE(last_day(DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4()*7, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'), 'week')) AS WEEK_LAST_DATE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>1000))
) as A
WHERE A.WEEK_LAST_DATE > '2016-09-07';
```

Why does the first query not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in SQL, you can't refer to an expression defined in the `select` clause in the same scope - left apart the `order by` clause. Typically, this raises a syntax error:

```
select t.*, 'abc' as newcol
from mytable t
where newcol = 'abc'
```

`newcol` is defined in the `select` clause, hence not available in the `where` clause. This is typically worked around by computing the value in an inner scope, then using it for filtering in an outer scope: subqueries, lateral joins, and common table expressions are the most common approaches. So:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 'abc' as newcol
    from mytable t
) t
where newcol = 'abc'
```

I am surprised that your first query even compiles; it may be some Snowflake-specific thing. But the second query is indeed the right way to do what you want:

Comment: Indeed I was expecting it to not compile.